# JAVA array pair for student grades

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, min

how do I pair the student array with the grade array? When I find the highest grade the corresponding student should also show, and same with the lowest graded student. I cant figure out how to make this program perform as such with two separate arrays.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Asm7 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("How many students do you have?: ");
    int AMOUNT = 0;
    AMOUNT = Scan.nextInt();
    
    String[] STUDENT = new String [AMOUNT];

    int COUNTER = 0;
    
    int GRADE [] = new int [AMOUNT];
    
    if (AMOUNT <= 0) {
        
        System.out.println("Invalid student amount");
       
    } 
    
    else {
    
    for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++){
        
    System.out.println("Enter student's first name: " + (i+1));
    STUDENT[i] = Scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter student's grade in order added: ");
    GRADE[i] = Scan.nextInt();  
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++){
        
    System.out.println(STUDENT[i] + " received the final grade of " + GRADE[i]);}
    System.out.println();
    
    
    int [] Results = MinMax(GRADE);
    
    System.out.println("The highest grade in the class was " + Results[1]);
    System.out.println("The lowest grade in the class was "+ Results[0]);
    
    }}
    
    public static int[] MinMax(int[] value) {
        
        int[] Result = new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
        for (int i : value) {
            Result[0] = i < Result[0] ? i : Result[0];
            Result[1] = i > Result[1] ? i : Result[1];
        }
        return Result;

    }
```

}

Comment: Your code has A LOT of issues. Both MinGrade and MaxGrade look incorrect. Your lowest and highest grade printouts are incorrect as well - you should print out the smallest after the loop not in each iteration. Start by making one thing right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop validation for ***number of students*** is a little late. You want to do this **before** you declare and initialize your arrays. However, the fact that the `while` loop was actually used in an attempt towards some form of validation is a really good sign. It's more than most new programmers tend to do. All input should be validated and provide a User the opportunity to supply a correct solution. This can only lead to a smoother, trouble free application and a much better experience for the User. Take a look at this `while` loop which is in your code:

```
while (amount < 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid student amount");
}
```

What is going to happen if the User supplies `-1` (this is a valid integer value as is +1)? That's right...your application will end up in an infinite loop spitting out `Invalid student amount` to the Console Window. Your validation scheme should encompass the entire prompt and then the means to exit it should be more logically defined. With a `while` loop the best exit is done through its conditional statement, if the condition is false then exit the loop, for example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
// Number Of Students...
String inputString = "";
while (inputString.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("How many students do you have?: --> ");
    inputString = scan.nextLine().trim();
    /* Is the supplied Number Of Students valid and within 
       range (1 to 50 inclusive)?     */
    if (!inputString.matches("\\d+") || Integer.valueOf(inputString) < 1 
                                     || Integer.valueOf(inputString) > 50) {
        // No...
        System.err.println("Invalid entry (" + inputString + ") for Student "
                         + "amount! Try again...");
        inputString = "";  // Empty inputString so we loop again.
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Valid amount provided.
int amount = Integer.valueOf(inputString);
String[] student = new String[amount];
int grade[] = new int[amount];
```

Right away you will notice some obvious changes here. The entire `How many students do you have?` prompt is contained within a `while` loop block. If the User does not supply a valid response then that User is asked to try again. The `student` and `grade` [*parallel* arrays](https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/parallel-arrays/) are declared and initialized only **after** a valid response for the *number of students* is provided.

You will also notice that the `while` loop condition doesn't rely on a integer value but instead it relies on actual string content (regardless of what it is) instead. If the variable is empty ("") then loop again. This is because the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method is used to collect the Users input instead of the [Scanner#nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) method. The prompt still expects an integer value to be supplied, just a string representation of an integer value and this is validated using the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex).

I personally prefer to use the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method for a number of reasons. I personally find it more flexible especially if you want to accept both Alpha and Numerical input from a single prompt. If the prompt above stated:

```
How many students do you have? (q to quit)
```

you would just need to add another `if` statement above the numerical validation code to see if 'q' or 'Q' was supplied, for example:

```
// If either q or Q is entered then quit application.
if (amountString.matches("[qQ]")) {
    System.out.println("Bye-Bye");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Also, with a good expression passed to the matches() method, there is no need to trap exceptions in order to carry out validations, not that there is anything wrong with this, many people do it, I especially don't however when I have no need to do so.

**Side Note:** I'm going  to state the obvious here and I'm sure you've heard it a hundred times before and you're sick of hearing it but I'm going to tell you again:

> Your class methods should start with a lowercase letter (see [Java Naming
> Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)).
> I know you don't hear the compiler complaining but it does make it a
> little more difficult (at times) to read the code. Everyone that reads
> your code will appreciate you for it.

Because the `student` and `grade` arrays are [*parallel* arrays](https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/parallel-arrays/) you would want the **minGrade()** and **maxGrade()** methods to return a specific array index value to either the lowest or highest grade so that a referential relationship can be made toward the student that contains that specific grade determined. So, this would be far more useful:

```
public static int minGrade(int[] arr, int size) {
    // Initialize min to have the highest possible value.
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int returnableIndex = -1;
    // loop to find lowest grade in array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
            returnableIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return returnableIndex;
}

public static int maxGrade(int[] arr, int size) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int returnableIndex = -1;
    // loop to find highest grade in array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
            returnableIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return returnableIndex;
}
```

With everything in play your code might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Number Of Students...
    String amountString = "";
    while (amountString.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("How many students do you have?: --> ");
        amountString = scan.nextLine().trim();
        
        // Is the supplied Number Of Students valid and within 
        // range (1 to 50 inclusive)?
        if (!amountString.matches("\\d+") || Integer.valueOf(amountString) < 1
                || Integer.valueOf(amountString) > 50) {
            // No...
            System.err.println("Invalid entry (" + amountString + ") for Student "
                    + "amount! Try again...");
            amountString = "";  // Empty inputString so we loop again.
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    // Valid amount provided.
    int amount = Integer.valueOf(amountString);

    // Declare and initialize parallel arrays
    String[] student = new String[amount];
    int grade[] = new int[amount];

    // Student Names and Grade...
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        // Student Name...
        String name = "";
        while (name.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter student #" + (i + 1) + " name: --> ");
            name = scan.nextLine().trim();
            /* Is the name valid (contains upper or lower case letters from
               A-Z and a single whitespaces separating first and last name?
               Whitespace and last name is optional.         */
            if (!name.matches("(?i)([a-z]+)(\\s{1})?([a-z]+)?")) {
                // No..
                System.err.println("Invalid Student #" + (i + 1) + " name ("
                        + name + ")! Try Again...");
                System.out.println();
                name = ""; // Empty name so we loop again.
            }
        }
        // Valid Student name provided...
        student[i] = name;

        // Student Grade...
        String gradeString = "";
        while (gradeString.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter student #" + (i + 1) + " grade: --> ");
            gradeString = scan.nextLine().trim();
            // Is the supplied grade valid and within range (0 to 100 inclusive)?
            if (!gradeString.matches("\\d+")
                    || Integer.valueOf(gradeString) < 0
                    || Integer.valueOf(gradeString) > 100) {
                // No...
                System.err.println("Invalid entry (" + gradeString + ") for "
                        + "Student #" + (i + 1) + " grade! Try again...");
                gradeString = "";
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        // Valid Student grade provided...
        grade[i] = Integer.valueOf(gradeString);
    }

    // Display everyone's grade
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.println(student[i] + " received the final grade of " + grade[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    //Display who is highest and lowest...
    int index = maxGrade(grade, amount);
    System.out.println("The highest grade in the class was by '" + student[index]
            + "' with a grade of: " + grade[index]);

    index = minGrade(grade, amount);
    System.out.println("The lowest grade in the class was by '" + student[index]
            + "' with a grade of: " + grade[index]);


}                                         

public static int minGrade(int[] arr, int size) {
    // Initialize min to have the highest possible value.
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int returnableIndex = -1;
    // loop to find lowest grade in array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
            returnableIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return returnableIndex;
}

public static int maxGrade(int[] arr, int size) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int returnableIndex = -1;
    // loop to find highest grade in array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
            returnableIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return returnableIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data are not sorted, it would be better to find both `min` and `max` grades in the same loop, after printing the students and their grades.

Then no loop is needed to print `min` and `max` grades:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    System.out.println(student[i] + " received the final grade of " + grade[i]);
}
int min = grade[0];
int max = grade[0];
for (int i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
    if (grade[i] < min) {
        min = grade[i];
    } else if (grade[i] > max) {
        max = grade[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("The highest grade in the class was " + max);
System.out.println("The lowest grade in the class was " + min);
```

If the index of min/max is sought, it would be possible to print the name of the students who get the min and max grades.

Comment: how would I do this within a method?

Comment: Make the method return an `int` value (min or max respectively) instead of `void`

Comment: Awesome do you know how to pair the student names with the grades so it not only shows max grade and low grade but the corresponding highest and lowest graded student

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] grades = new int[]{50, 51, 52, 50, 60, 22, 53, 70, 60, 94, 56, 41};

    int[] result = getMinMax(grades);

    System.out.println("Min: " + result[0] + ", Max: " + result[1]);
}

public static int[] getMinMax(int[] values) {

    int[] result = new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
    for (int i : values) {
        result[0] = i < result[0] ? i : result[0];
        result[1] = i > result[1] ? i : result[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You'll need to handle the case of int[] values being null or empty. You can decide that (Throw an exception, return null... or whatever)

Comment: thanks for this particular assignment the min and max have to be through a method and for loop

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Perfect thank you that worked and updated, now do you know how to pair the names with the grades too?

Comment: Yeah. Modify the getMinMax method to return the min and max INDEX (not value). Then you can get the name and grade using the min and max index values with the Studen[] and Grade[] arrays.